# Как решить CS1674 в случае ее возникновения при объявлении типа внутри оператора using

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Это моя первая C# + EF программа, Я создал класс-контекста данных для другого моего класса (platform) и метод для соединения с MS SQL Server:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Platform> Platforms { get; set; } = null!;

    public AppContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Platformsdb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```

После чего, в Programm начал писать следующий код для добавления данных в БД:

```
using (AppContext db = new AppContext())
{
    Platform pl = new();
    db.Platforms.Add(pl);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Где словил CS1674 - type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' при создании объекта AppContext.

Я пытался реализовать IDisposable для AppContext - не помогло;
Явное приведение тоже проблемы не решило.

Comment: А если будет таки нужен, то нужно, чтобы ваш класс был унаследован от `IDisposable`, без этого реализовывать методы без толку.

Comment: Комментаторам: `DbContext` является disposable.

Comment: Вот это уберите из конструктора: `Database.EnsureDeleted(); Database.EnsureCreated();` - иначе БД будет удаляться и создаваться заново при каждом использовании AppContext.

Comment: Всегда указывайте точную версию Entity Framework, которую используете.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Спасибо, Использовал 6.0.6 версию. Вопрос с ошибкой решен.

Comment: @AlexF - `public class AppContext : DbContext` - из кода автора

Comment: Методы `EnsureDeleted` и `EnsureCreated` существуют только в Entity Framework **Core**. Указывайте **точную** версию! Не только номер, но и **название**.

Comment: _Вопрос с ошибкой решен._ - Как решен?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Приму к сведению, благодарю! Произошла ошибка в т.ч из-за нейминга AppContext - это класс в .Net, а я назвал этим именем свой класс, возможно из-за этого и появилась ошибка... Я переназвал класс и ошибка была устранена

Comment: А, теперь ясно. Действительно, конфликт имён. Можно явно указывать неймспейс, но лучше действительно переименовать.